# How to place a node in a sequence after calculating total sum of it's attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am very new in XSLT transformation...  I have an xml file like the following :-

```
<OTA_CruiseReq>
 <GuestCounts>
     <GuestCount Quantity="2"/>
     <GuestCount Quantity="3"/>
     <GuestCount Quantity="1"/>
     <GuestCount Quantity="1"/>
     <GuestCount Quantity="1"/>
 </GuestCounts>
</OTA_CruiseReq>
```

Now.. I want to create an XSLT that would calculate the total number of **quantity** of GuestCount and result in following output xml :-

```
<PersonNos>
            <PersonNo>1</PersonNo>
            <PersonNo>2</PersonNo>
            <PersonNo>3</PersonNo>
            <PersonNo>4</PersonNo>
            <PersonNo>5</PersonNo>
            <PersonNo>6</PersonNo>
            <PersonNo>7</PersonNo>
            <PersonNo>8</PersonNo>
</PersonNos>
```

That is it will calculate the total number of **quantity** and display the `<PersonNo>` till that sequence ... for example here total **quantity** of GuestCount  is 2+3+1+1+1 =**8** .. so `<PersonNo>` will be displayed from 1 to 8 ...
I tried the following :-

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <PersonNos>
    <xsl:for-each select="sum(OTA_CruiseReq/GuestCounts/GuestCount/@Quantity)">
       <PersonNo><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></PersonNo>
     </xsl:for-each>     
       </PersonNos>
</xsl:template>
```

But for each doesn't support any number .. please help to resolve it in a very way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, your `sum` expression is not quite right. You are summing the `@Quantity` attributes, so it should look like this:

```
sum(OTA_CruiseReq/GuestCounts/GuestCount/@Quantity))
```

Now, you have tagged this XSLT 2.0, which means you can use a 'for' loop with an incremented counter, like so

```
<xsl:for-each select="1 to xs:integer(sum(OTA_CruiseReq/GuestCounts/GuestCount/@Quantity))">
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="/">
 <PersonNos>
     <xsl:for-each select="1 to xs:integer(sum(OTA_CruiseReq/GuestCounts/GuestCount/@Quantity))">
        <PersonNo><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></PersonNo>
     </xsl:for-each>     
 </PersonNos>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

On the otherhand, if you are actually only using XSLT 1.0, then you will need a recursive template to do the incrementing.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <PersonNos>
            <xsl:call-template name="person">
                <xsl:with-param name="end" select="sum(OTA_CruiseReq/GuestCounts/GuestCount/@Quantity)" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </PersonNos>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="person">
        <xsl:param name="start" select="1" />
        <xsl:param name="end" />

        <xsl:if test="not($start > $end)">
            <PersonNo><xsl:value-of select="$start"/></PersonNo>
            <xsl:call-template name="person">
                <xsl:with-param name="start" select="$start + 1" />
                <xsl:with-param name="end" select="$end" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response ....Getting following exception :- 23:00:18,309 ERROR [main] JAXPSAXProcessorInvoker  - Syntax error in '1 to xs:integer(sum(OTA_CruiseReq/GuestCounts/GuestCount/@Quantity))'.

Comment: I am guessing that despite you tagging your question XSLT 2.0, that your XSLT processor only supports XSLT 1.0. I have added a solution for XSLT 1.0 if this is the case.